# Pass Data from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, php, python, node.js, cgi

I am constantly receiving data in JavaScript. I want to pass this data as input to Python program. How to implement this?

---

Data will be received as **string** in **JavaScript** on my browser. I have written a **Python** program where **I need this string** to do certain things. So, how can I pass the string received by JavaScript in my browser to the Python program?

I tried using `exec` in **PHP** along with `raw_input()` in **Python**. However, it didn't work as expected.

Note - I will constantly be receiving string on my browser. Hence, I need to constantly pass the strings to the Python program. Any language will work for me as long as it's supported both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I'm not understanding the python script have to be done client or server side ?

Comment: Technically it needs to be done on the client side. However, since I'm the client too, I have full control over client side device.

Answer (score 0):

based on your information,it feels like you will be repeatedly call a function after setting the value in java script ,it will be better you create a simple rest-service and call it e.g: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/python-scripting-tutorial/create-simple-rest-web-service-with-python.php